# missing css when url rewrite using .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

1. this is the first time to me to rewrite url using .htaccess.
2. when I rewrite the url my css was missing
3. here is my code:

   ```
   RewriteEngine On

   RewriteBase /blog/

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d [NC]

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [NC]

   RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/([^/.]+)/?$ catview.php?ctid=$1&cet_slug=$2 [QSA,L]
   ```

I need the url: `blog/9/iphone`

It's working but missing css!
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

You can use following code of .htaccess by which you can acheive your requirement:

## not rewrite css, js and images

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(?:css|js|jpe?g|gif|png)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^xyz/(.+)/(.+)/ abc.php?id=$1&name=$2 [L]
```

## rewrite css, js and images, from root

```
RewriteRule ^xyz/[^/]+/[^/]+/(.+)$ $1  [L]
```